Next.js App router behavior in building a page when generateStaticParams is provided and layout is dynamic

this is my folder structure
I am using next.js 14
in root layout i use user data to display user avatar which cause all pages become dynamic
in page.js inside  /cabins/[cabinId]   i have exported generateStaticParams  this page also renders root layout ( which is what we want )
when i build the project despite the dynamic root layout ,   page.js for  /cabins/[cabinId] is marked as SSG


this is what build says
when i comment the dynamic part in the root layout and  build  the about page become Static   and
/cabins/[cabinId] does not change
log story short ,  I expected the /cabins/[cabinId]  to be dynamic  but it is  SSG
can anybody explain how Next.js renders  dynamic layout and SSG  page  for client ?
